# JSON error in console: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, json

Here is my json http://jsbin.com/wagomomuda/1/edit

when I try to run, I get an error as unexpected token :, i tried validating my json, in many sites, it says its valid.Can anyone please help me out with this, as I am new to json.

Comment: Please just post your code, not a link to the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the bellow json

var jsonvarable='{"content":{"comments":[{"userName":"ElizabethEstes","currentDate":"-09/10/2014","currentTime":",08:42AM","image":"ellizabeth_estes.png","data":"Cumsociisnatoquepenatibusetmagnisdisparturientmontes,nasceturridiculusmus.Vivamussagittislacusvelauguelaoreetrutrun"},{"userName":"BillBaggins","currentDate":"-09/10/2014","currentTime":",08:42AM","image":"john-smith_img.png","data":"Cumsociisnatoquepenatibusetmagnisdisparturientmontes,nasceturridiculusmus.Vivamussagittislacusvelauguelaoreetrutrun"},{"userName":"SarahSmith","currentDate":"-09/10/2014","currentTime":",08:42AM","image":"sarah.png","data":"Cumsociisnatoquepenatibusetmagnisdisparturientmontes,nasceturridiculusmus.Vivamussagittislacusvelauguelaoreetrutrun"}]}}';

Answer (score 0):

your json is valid,but your script is invalid, code between { } is a code block,so your code looks like

```
"content":{ ......}
```

add this is a invalid script

you may change it to

```
var myJson = {"content":{ ......}};
```